# Render objects, use them as search links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search

I'm still fairly new to Rails.  I'm starting to get the hang of it but what I want to do is beyond me at the moment.  I've done a lot of research and there's plenty on making search boxes, but I want to streamline the process.  So, I have a view helper that does this:

```
<% if @events.any? %>
  <ol class="events">
    <%= render @events %>
  </ol>
<% end %>
```

which works fine, this shows a user's own events.  I get a list of event objects that consists of 3 lines per object, `:city`, `:event_name`, and `:event_date`.  What I want to do is to be able to click the object, either `:city` or both `:city`/`:event_date` lines, and show results from a search that looks for all the events that have that same `:city` AND `:event_date`.  FWIW I'm using drop-downs for getting the city and date for the event object so there won't be user typing differences.  I think I need to go ahead and render the view myself, something like

```
<% @events.each do |e| %>
    <%= link_to e.city, searchlinkthingie %>
<% end %>
```

along with an associated search controller to grab the results and throw up a new page, and a new route as well.  I've not tried building the controller and route yet because I can't quite figure out what it needs to look like.  I've been reading up on `link_to` and I'm thinking I need to go ahead and make the link directly, but again, not sure what it should look like.  I'm about ready to put my head through my monitor.  Thoughts?

edit: The solution inspired by the answer below was to make a `link_to` with two joined strings for both city and event date and `search_url(params[:search1 event.city, :search2 event.date])`, make an associated search method in the events controller that called a `self.search` method in the events model, and a 'match' in routes.rb.  The model did an SQL query using AND that returned the results I wanted, displayed using a simple helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you build the search so that you can enter arbitrary cities and get back the results you want. That's step one. The search controller actions are going to accept a parameter that is the search string. Let's say that parameter is called `query`.

So, you have something like a `search_controller` with an action called `search`, and that action takes the value of `params[:query]` to return results.

Once you've got that, you can build links to pre-defined searches like so:

```
<%= link_to e.city, search_search_path(:query => e.city) %>
```

This link triggers a request to the `search` action on the `search_controller` (hence the path `search_search_path`), setting the `query` parameter to `e.city`.

Finally, since this action doesn't work with a particular record, it would be a `:collection` rather than `:member` route. So, depending on your naming convention, the entry in your `routes.rb` file would look something like:

```
config.resource :search do
  get :search, :on => :collection
end
```

Which should result in a url that looks something like:

```
http://example.com/search/search?query=chicago
```

Where `/search/search/` maps to the `search` action on the `search` controller, with the `query` parameter included.

You could also enter a matching rule (Rails 3 style shown here) that would shorten that URL even further:

```
match "/search" => "search#search"
```

Which would allow you to have a url like:

```
http://example.com/search?query=chicago
```

...that would work the same as the previous example.

Comment: This pointed me in the right direction.  I ended up going with 'search' inside the events data model.  search_events_controller didn't work, kept getting undefined method, but search_url did work, perhaps the route I setup was wrong for the former?  In any case, this answer did help but I ended up going with an almost completely different solution.  Should I accept this answer and edit the solution into the OP or just go ahead and make a new answer?

Comment: Ah, I meant to put it as `search_search_path` - my mistake (updated). Your addition of `url` should also work.

Comment: Good to know.  Updated OP with my solution and accepted your answer.  Thanks!